# FEEDBACK - New company logo design for ecommerce website, packaging, collateral

Tags: logo, critique

I have a two part question defined as **A** and **B**. The purpose is to get **(A)** feedback on strength of company logo (name, colors, font and size). In addition, **(B)** feedback on the treatment of product names added to the company logo. For example, "XYZ Company" (*company name*) "Widgets" (*product*), making "**XYZ Company Widgets**".

**(A)** I created a name that means something to me and hopefully is creative. Here are background details of my company name - beeJACK

1. My nickname is "**bee**", and my dad's "**Jack**." My father recently passed and it has been very difficult for me. He is someone who always kept rooting me on, believed in me when no other family members would. Therefore, I wanted his name to be all in caps - JACK
2. The bee icon:

- Reflects my nickname and, the body and wing create a "B"
- The symbol of a bee signifies in Christianity activity, work, diligence and good order.
- As a spiritual animal, when a bee appears in your life, the most common message it carries has to do with your levels of productivity. *[NOTE: by nature I am energetic, cannot sit still, always striving to do better]*
- The bee spirit has a strong work ethic.
- Technically speaking, a bee shouldn't be able to fly--it's designed wrong for aerodynamics. From a spiritual perspective, this speaks to our limitations and how to move past them successfully.

3. I didn't want the bee image to be portrayed as soft and fuzzy. I want it creative, edgy and possessing  confidence, attitude, steadiness, boldness, it knows what it wants, no fear, it has direction and things that get in its way will be stung (the long trailing stinger)
4. The colors represented are my favorite color - green and my father's - purple

- the eye, antenna and back wing are black
- the bee's head, other wing, body outline and stinger (which is a gradation) are purple
- the stripes on the bee body are green

5. The font is Malgun Gothic bold. I want the name to be clear and not fluffy, squiggly. The font and icon together are cohesive

[image: beeJACK]

**(B)** *[NOTE: see comment in initial first paragraph above]* My first product is a pocket "**flaps**" that is temporarily affixed to the top edge of an apparel pocket which does not have a flap (e.g. jeans back pocket, shorts back pocket, leggings, shirts, jackets).

1. Logo will then become, "**beeJACK flaps**"

- "bee" will be the same color as the bee icon purple
- "JACK" will be all caps, black
- treatment of product will be in same font, however green to match the stripes on the bee body
  [image: beeJACK flaps product]

Your feedback, opinions and comments I will seriously take into consideration.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is totally off-topic, but the claim that "bees shouldn't be able to fly" is [false](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/interviews/myth-bees-shouldnt-be-able-fly). It's an urban myth.

Comment: (1) How will look the logo for 1 or 2 color reproduction? It will happen someday. You need to be prepared. (3) The antennas too thin, they can disappear in rough and/or small size reproduction. (2) Alas, "B" looks more like "3" -- 3eeJACK

Comment: It's an insect and eeJACK. Let the text be text. It frees the image to have more character. Check this to see what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2UMV.png

Comment: I didn't see the B.. never would if I didn't also read the name. And, to me, it's a wasp.... `:)` I understand you don't want it "cute and fuzzy", but bees in general, have smaller short, fat, bodies, with less separated heads and smaller wings [GIS](https://www.google.com/search?q=mean+bee+cartoon+illustration&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwij34nrhLHwAhUYtJ4KHZN0CloQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=mean+bee+cartoon+illustration&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CbZFiPaGCFamgAcAB4AYABuAKIAb0IkgEFMi0yLjKYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=mcWRYOOuIpjo-gST6anQBQ&bih=1258&biw=1494)

Comment: If you can just make "ee" of Bee also in illustrated way like B and make them a bit bigger, it could increase readability of Bee.

Comment: And sorry for your loss, I just gone through your details :(

Answer (score 1):

The "bee" looks angry IMHO. It looks more like a wasp. The stinger is too long and I agree with the other comment that it looks like "ee JACK"..it is not cohesive enough. But I see where you are going..you just need a few more versions, I'm sure it will come together.
I understand the reasoning for the colors, but maybe a compromise, since you already use the names.. either use normal bee colors, or use desired colors and think of different name?? Just a thought... Good luck.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I've got a Version 2 that I will be asking for feedback on.

Comment: My hot take is that it looks like either "eeJACK" or maybe "KeeJACK".  Even after reading that it should be a "B", I have trouble seeing it.  I also agree, the eye especially looks angry and the stinger way too long.  Even with the stinger, however, due to the colors, it looks more like some form of butterfly than a bee to me.  The black curve at the top I also don't think does you any benefit; it's not an antennae, nor a wing, so I'm not sure what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Colours are not harmonious, seem a bit randomly picked and also they are way outside the CMYK spectrum which is not ideal for printing.

Bee seems to be in between about 4 graphic styles. Eyes look like from a manga, back wing looks like a calligraphy stroke gone wrong, head like clipart and front wing like a form made in ms paint. Also first look I thought it's a butterfly.

It very much reads "eeJack" – partly because the blue head and sting make it look less like a "B", partly because the sketchy "B" does not feel like part of the same word as the "ee" and I would argue it is closer to a "3" than to a "B" at the moment. Also the scale of the "B" compared to the "ee" does not help.

In general the logo idea says more about you than the product/company. Which is not necessary bad. May work well with friends/family/market stalls but would assume less for example for online shops, where people do not get that "bee" is your nickname and therefore have no idea what the bee stands for.